# How can I detect a click in a JLabel with mouse movement? (like JButton)?

Tags: java, swing, click, jbutton, jlabel

I would like to detect mouse click events in a JLabel, in a way similar to the "ActionListener.actionPerformed()" functionality that is available for a JButton. 
How can I do this? Additional details follow.

The functions of the MouseAdapter class are not identical to the ActionListener functionality that is available for a JButton. The MouseAdapter.mouseClicked() function will not register a mouseclick if the mouse pointer moves (even slightly) between the mousePressed and mouseReleased events, which makes the interface sometimes "miss" intended clicks.

Alternatively, the MouseAdapter.mousePressed() event can detect all clicks, but in that case, each click is registered before the mouse button is released. (Which might be unexpected behavior for some users.)

In the JButton ActionListener.actionPerformed() event, a mouse click will be registered even if you press the mouse button down, move the pointer around, and then release the mouse button. (This is true as long as the pointer does not leave the JButton boundaries). I'd like to know how to implement this more robust click detection behavior for a single click and/or a double-click on a JLabel?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "robust clicking" functionality you described can be accomplished using a custom MouseAdapter class. Pasted below is a copy of the MouseLiberalAdapter class I wrote to properly catch "moving" mouse click events in a JLabel (or in other swing components).

Instructions to use the MouseLiberalAdapter  class:

- Copy the class into your project.
- Extend the MouseLiberalAdapter class, and override the mouse events that you wish to catch.
- The mouseLiberalClick() and mouseLiberalDoubleClick() events provide the functionality that you described. These will detect mouse clicks, even if the mouse moves between the "mouse pressed" and "mouse released" part of the clicking process.
- If you're not yet familiar with how to catch swing events, then you may wish to also look up examples of how to use the standard Java "MouseAdapter" class. The MouseLiberalAdapter class is used in a similar way to the MouseAdapter class.
- See also: The MouseLiberalAdapter class javadoc comments.

**Example usage:**

```
    JLabel labelSingleClick = new JLabel("Single click me.");
    JLabel labelDoubleClick = new JLabel("Double click me.");
    labelSingleClick.addMouseListener(new MouseLiberalAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseLiberalClick(MouseEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Single click detected.");
        }
    });
    labelDoubleClick.addMouseListener(new MouseLiberalAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseLiberalDoubleClick(MouseEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Double click detected.");
        }
    });
```

**MouseLiberalAdapter class:**

```
    package com.project.utilities;

    import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;

    /**
     * MouseLiberalAdapter.
     *
     * This class extends the MouseAdapter class, to include two additional events. The added events are
     * the mouseLiberalClick() and the mouseLiberalDoubleClick(). By default, the mouseClick() event in
     * the MouseAdapter has a limitation. The mouseClick() event cannot register a click if the mouse
     * pointer moves even slightly, between the mouse press and mouse release events. By contrast, the
     * mouseLiberalClick() will register a "liberal mouse click" even if the mouse moves (by any amount)
     * during the click event, as long as the mouse pointer does not leave the boundaries of the
     * component which is generating the mouse events. (This "liberal mouse click" behavior duplicates
     * the "actionPerformed()" functionality that exists in the JButton class.)
     *
     * Note: This class is frequently used to detect clicks in a JLabel, but it can be used in any swing
     * component that will accept a MouseAdapter.
     *
     * Using this class is similar to using the MouseAdapter class. (See also: The MouseAdapter
     * javadocs.) To use this class, you would extend this class and override any (non-final) event
     * methods that are of interest.
     *
     * The original MouseAdapter functions have been marked as final, and cannot be overridden. However,
     * the class still provides all the original functions (with slightly modified function names). The
     * two new functions are also provided: mouseLiberalClick() and mouseLiberalDoubleClick(). A usage
     * example is shown below.
     *
     * Usage example:
     * <pre> {@code
     * JLabel labelSingleClick = new JLabel("Single click me.");
     * JLabel labelDoubleClick = new JLabel("Double click me.");
     * labelSingleClick.addMouseListener(new MouseLiberalAdapter() {
     * @Override
     * public void mouseLiberalClick(MouseEvent e) {
     * JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Single click detected.");
     * }
     * });
     * labelDoubleClick.addMouseListener(new MouseLiberalAdapter() {
     * @Override
     * public void mouseLiberalDoubleClick(MouseEvent e) {
     * JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Double click detected.");
     * }
     * });
     * }</pre>
     */
    public abstract class MouseLiberalAdapter extends MouseAdapter {

        /**
         * isComponentPressedDown, This indicates whether or not the component is currently
         * (conceptually) "pressed down". To understand the meaning of "pressed down", consider the
         * behavior of a JButton. When you press the mouse inside a button, the button redraws itself to
         * indicate a "press down" state. If you release the mouse while inside the button, a button
         * click will be registered, and the button will switch to a "not press down" state. The button
         * can also become "not pressed down" if the mouse pointer leaves the boundaries of the button
         * without first releasing the mouse.
         */
        private boolean isComponentPressedDown = false;
        /**
         * lastUnusedLiberalSingleClickTimeStamp, This stores a timestamp for the mouse release of the
         * last unused liberal single click. If a single click is "used" as part of a double click, then
         * it's timestamp will no longer be stored here. If there is no liberal single click which fits
         * the above description, then this will contain the value zero.
         */
        private long lastUnusedLiberalSingleClickTimeStamp = 0;
        /**
         * slowestDoubleClickMilliseconds, This constant indicates the maximum time window in which a
         * liberal double click can occur. More specifically, this indicates the maximum time, in
         * milliseconds, between liberal single click mouse releases, that will be considered to
         * constitute a liberal double click.
         */
        private final int slowestDoubleClickMilliseconds = 1800;

        /**
         * mouseLiberalClick, Override this function to catch liberal single click events.
         *
         * Note: The mouse event which is passed to this function will be the mouse event that was
         * received from the "mouseRelease" event at the end of the liberal single click.
         */
        public void mouseLiberalClick(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        /**
         * mouseLiberalDoubleClick, Override this function to catch liberal double click events.
         *
         * Note: The mouse event which is passed to this function will be the mouse event that was
         * received from the "mouseRelease" event at the end of the liberal double click.
         */
        public void mouseLiberalDoubleClick(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        /**
         * mouseClick, Override this function to catch standard mouse click events.
         */
        public void mouseClick(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        /**
         * mousePress, Override this function to catch standard mouse press events.
         */
        public void mousePress(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        /**
         * mouseRelease, Override this function to catch standard mouse release events.
         */
        public void mouseRelease(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        /**
         * mouseEnter, Override this function to catch standard mouse enter events.
         */
        public void mouseEnter(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        /**
         * mouseExit, Override this function to catch standard mouse exit events.
         */
        public void mouseExit(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        /**
         * mouseWheelMove, Override this function to catch standard mouse wheel move events.
         */
        public void mouseWheelMove(MouseWheelEvent e) {
        }

        /**
         * mouseDrag, Override this function to catch standard mouse drag events.
         */
        public void mouseDrag(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        /**
         * mouseMove, Override this function to catch standard mouse move events.
         */
        public void mouseMove(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        /**
         * mousePressed, Final function. Handles mouse pressed events.
         */
        @Override
        final public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // Record that the component is "pressed down".
            isComponentPressedDown = true;
            // Call the mouse press event.
            mousePress(e);
        }

        /**
         * mouseReleased, Final function. Handles mouse released events. This function also detects
         * liberal single clicks, and liberal double clicks.
         */
        @Override
        final public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // Check to see if this mouse release completes a liberal single click.
            if (isComponentPressedDown) {
                // A liberal single click has occurred.
                mouseLiberalClick(e);
                // Check to see if we had two liberal single clicks within the double click time window.
                long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long timeBetweenUnusedClicks = now - lastUnusedLiberalSingleClickTimeStamp;
                if (timeBetweenUnusedClicks <= slowestDoubleClickMilliseconds) {
                    // A liberal double click has occurred.
                    mouseLiberalDoubleClick(e);
                    // Mark the single click timestamp as "used" by this double click.
                    lastUnusedLiberalSingleClickTimeStamp = 0;
                } else {
                    // Save the single click timestamp as part of a possible future double click.
                    lastUnusedLiberalSingleClickTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
            }
            // Record the mouse release.
            isComponentPressedDown = false;
            // Call the mouse release event.
            mouseRelease(e);
        }

        /**
         * mouseEntered, Final function. Handles mouse entered events.
         */
        @Override
        final public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            // Call the mouse enter event.
            mouseEnter(e);
        }

        /**
         * mouseExited, Final function. Handles mouse exited events.
         */
        @Override
        final public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            // Since the mouse left the component, the component is no longer considered "press down".
            isComponentPressedDown = false;
            // Call the mouse exit event.
            mouseExit(e);
        }

        /**
         * mouseClicked, Final function. Handles mouse clicked events.
         */
        @Override
        final public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // Call the mouse click event.
            mouseClick(e);
        }

        /**
         * mouseWheelMoved, Final function. Handles mouse wheel moved events.
         */
        @Override
        final public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
            // Call the mouse wheel move event.
            mouseWheelMove(e);
        }

        /**
         * mouseDragged, Final function. Handles mouse dragged events.
         */
        @Override
        final public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            // Call the mouse drag event.
            mouseDrag(e);
        }

        /**
         * mouseMoved, Final function. Handles mouse moved events.
         */
        @Override
        final public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            // Call the mouse move event.
            mouseMove(e);
        }
    }
```